# discord.js - How to read data from embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to get color of the embed in message. That message has an embed (with color), but it still says `false` in log.

```
let messageId = '922497690359716898';

if(messageId.embeds){
    let applicationAuthor = messageId.embeds.color;

    console.log(applicationAuthor)
} else console.log('false');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single ID/snowflake doesn't have an `embeds` property. You need to [fetch the message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) by this ID first and check its `embeds` once it's resolved.

If the message with the embed is in the same channel as the message with the command, you can use this:

```js
let messageId = '922497690359716898';
try {
  let messageWithEmbed = await msg.channel.messages.fetch(messageId);
  if (messageWithEmbed.embeds?.[0]) {
    let color = messageWithEmbed.embeds[0].color;
    console.log(color);
  } else {
    console.log('no embed found')
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```